# Angular-CLI HMR refresh entire page everytime

Tags: angular, angular-cli, webpack-hmr

Hello i am using Angular CLI (beta.22) with HMR.

It worked correctly somehow, but now with every change, the entire page will be refreshed. With error in console:

> annot apply update. Need to do a full reload!(anonymous function) @ dev-server.js:33ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232Zone.run @ zone.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401
>   vendor.bundle.js:55305 [HMR] Error: A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first.
>       at assertPlatform (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:27579:15)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:27564:16
>       at bootstrap (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:273:132)
>       at hmrBootstrap (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:1094:5)
>       at Object. (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:277:90)
>       at Object.494 (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:288:30)
>       at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:686:30)
>       at hotApply (http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:613:14)
>       at hotUpdateDownloaded (http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:311:13)
>       at hotAddUpdateChunk (http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:291:13)

Comment: Hmm i have already realized, it doesnt work for LAZY routes only.. If i use it with normal routes.. it works.